# R: create single new column based upon matching string in multiple other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with a very large number of string column variables representing procedural codes. There is another column of variables that represents the coding format (some are ICD9, some are other more arcane formats). Each observation is a patient. I need to:

1. Search through each variable name with a particular prefix
2. Ensure that the code being used is an ICD9 code (represented by "02").
3. Find which of these codes match the first 3 characters of a particular string
4. Create a new column variable =1 if any of the variables begin with those three characters, and =0 if none matched

There are too many variables for it to be trivial to create a list of each of them manually via c("cd1", "cd2", ...), and I potentially need to do this many different times so I'd like to make it as general a solution as possible.

Here's a simplified sample, where the strings I need to search for begin with "231":

```
ID   cd1    type1  cd2    type2  cd3    type3  cd4    type4
1    "231"  "02"   "219"  "02"   "1321" "02"  "2314"  "02"
2    "222"  "02"  
3    "123"  "142"   
4    "145"  "02"   "521"  "02"   "2313" "02"   
5    "231"  "01"
```

The output I'd like is:

```
ID   cd1    type1  cd2    type2  cd3    type3  cd4    type4   flag_var
1    "231"  "02"   "219"  "02"   "1321" "02"  "2314"  "02"    1
2    "222"  "02"                                              0
3    "123"  "142"                                             0
4    "145"  "02"   "521"  "02"   "2313" "02"                  1
5    "231"  "01"                                              0
```

(ID #5 is set to 0 because, even though the cd1 code is "231", the type1 variable is "01" and thus not in the correct coding format")

I've been somewhat successful in accomplishing this using mutate and case_when:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(flag_var = case_when(
    startsWith(cd1, "231") ~ 1, 
    startsWith(cd2, "231") ~ 1, 
    startsWith(cd3, "231") ~ 1, 
    startsWith(cd4, "231") ~ 1, 
    TRUE ~ 0))
```

Like I said, the actual dataset has too many variables and potential searches for it to make sense to hard-code it in the manner above. I think there should be a good way to do this using mutate_at or another dplyr function, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I've been able to use the following code to get a set of new variables equal to 1 or 0, but not a single variable. I can then use rowSums to sum across all columns and check if this value is nonzero. But it's ugly and laborious:

```
df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("cd")),
                       funs(testvar = ifelse(startsWith(., "231"), 1, 0)))
test_names = df %>% select(ends_with("_testvar")) %>% names()
df <- df %>% mutate(flag_var = (rowSums(.[test_names]) == 1))
df <- df %>% select(-ends_with("_testvar"))
```

Anyone have any simpler ideas? Thanks so much!

EDIT: I realized that I also have to incorporate coding type variables. The initial sample data tables have been edited to reflect this.

Comment: This is definitely beyond my CRAN 'icd' package, and 'dplyr' is a good tool for the job; just a reminder that 'icd' might help with pre-processing, code validation, and more complicated comorbidity calculations that you might need.

Answer (score 1):

This might answer question or do you need the 0-1 as row values?

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(~ID,   ~cd1,      ~cd2,      ~cd3,      ~cd4,
        1,    "231",    "219",    "1321",   "2314",
        2,    "222",    ""      , ""    ,   "",
        3,    "123",    "142",    ""    ,   "",
        4,    "145",    "521",    "2313",   "122")

dat %>% 
  gather("cd_type", "code", 2:5) %>% 
  mutate(flag_var = case_when(
    startsWith(code, "231") ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  ))
#> # A tibble: 16 x 4
#>       ID cd_type code  flag_var
#>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1     1 cd1     231          1
#>  2     2 cd1     222          0
#>  3     3 cd1     123          0
#>  4     4 cd1     145          0
#>  5     1 cd2     219          0
#>  6     2 cd2     ""           0
#>  7     3 cd2     142          0
#>  8     4 cd2     521          0
#>  9     1 cd3     1321         0
#> 10     2 cd3     ""           0
#> 11     3 cd3     ""           0
#> 12     4 cd3     2313         1
#> 13     1 cd4     2314         1
#> 14     2 cd4     ""           0
#> 15     3 cd4     ""           0
#> 16     4 cd4     122          0
```

Or do this to get back into original wide format

```r
dat %>% 
  gather("cd_type", "code", 2:5) %>% 
  mutate(flag_var = case_when(
    startsWith(code, "231") ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  )) %>% 
  spread(cd_type, code) %>% 
  select(ID, cd1:cd4, flag_var)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>      ID cd1   cd2   cd3   cd4   flag_var
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1     1 <NA>  219   1321  <NA>         0
#> 2     1 231   <NA>  <NA>  2314         1
#> 3     2 222   ""    ""    ""           0
#> 4     3 123   142   ""    ""           0
#> 5     4 145   521   <NA>  122          0
#> 6     4 <NA>  <NA>  2313  <NA>         1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, that seems like an elegant method. You can see from your example though that it actually doesn't return the data unchanged. IDs #1 and #4 now have two observations each when the data is returned to wide format. The final dataset form needs to be unchanged from how it started, except with a new column added. Is this possible with your method?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
df$flag_var <- 1*(rowSums(substring(as.matrix(df[, 2:ncol(df)]), 1, 3) == '231') > 0)

#   ID cd1 cd2  cd3  cd4 flag_var
# 1  1 231 219 1321 2314        1
# 2  2 222                      0
# 3  3 123 142                  0
# 4  4 145 521 2313  122        1
```

For the updated example, since the `cd` columns and `type` columns are paired, the following code should work:

```
cd.cols <- grepl('^cd', colnames(df))
type.cols <- grepl('^type', colnames(df))

flag <- substring(as.matrix(df[,cd.cols]), 1, 3) == '231' & df[,type.cols] == '02'
df$flag_var <- 1 * (rowSums(flag) > 0)

# > df
#   ID cd1 type1 cd2 type2  cd3 type3  cd4 type4 flag_var
# 1  1 231    02 219    02 1321    02 2314    02        1
# 2  2 222    02                                        0
# 3  3 123   142                                        0
# 4  4 145    02 521    02 2313    02                   1
# 5  5 231    01                                        0
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this works beautifully. I realized there's another wrinkle to my dataset, which is that there's an additional variable that complicates things (see my original post which has been edited).

Answer (score 1):

We could loop through the columns and do a partial match with `grepl`, `Reduce` the `list` of `vector`s to a single logical `vector` and coerce the values to binary

```
df$flag_var <- +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[-1], grepl, pattern = '^231')))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), cd1 = c("231", "222", 
"123", "145"), cd2 = c("219", "", "142", "521"), cd3 = c("1321", 
 "", "", "2313"), cd4 = c("2314", "", "", "122")), row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L), class = "data.frame")
```